# Why does ruby koans accept the exception message in line 5 but not in line 10?

Tags: methods, argument-error

```
1. def test_calling_global_methods_with_wrong_number_of_arguments
2.    exception = assert_raise(ArgumentError) do
3.      my_global_method
4.    end
5.    assert_match(/wrong number of arguments \(0 for 2\)/, exception.message)
6.
7.    exception = assert_raise(ArgumentError) do
8.      my_global_method(1,2,3)
9.    end
10.   assert_match(/wrong number or arguments \(3 for 2\)/, exception.message)
11. end
```

line 5 worked perfectly. But when i make the same edit in line 10, why do i get the error message saying:  Expected "wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)" to match /wrong number or arguments \(3 for 2\)/

Am i missing something?

Comment: what do you mean by "before correcting it for line 10"?  What are you typing?  What is the exact error message?

Comment: @La-comadreja sorry for my poor language. I mean i am getting this error for line 10- Expected "wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)" to match /wrong number or arguments /(3 for 2/)/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the assertion in line 10, 'or' instead of 'of'

```
wrong number or arguments
```

Comment: Apparently, when i deleted the previous code and re-wrote the same code again, it worked. I see why now. THANKYOU!!

Comment: i tried to, but i donot have enough reputations yet! I will as soon as i get there :)